# Replace values in a Pandas column to be the same for all unique values in another column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, replace

What I have is a large Pandas dataframe in Python that looks something like this:

```
df_test = pd.DataFrame(data = None, columns = ['file','source'])
df_test.file = ['file_1', 'file_1', 'file_2', 'file_2', 'file_3', 'file_3']
df_test.source = ['nasa', 'unknown', 'esa', 'unknown', 'jaxa', 'unknown']
```

What I want to get from this is that all values in the 'file' column with the same name should have the same value in the 'source' column, and not be 'unknown'. It should then look like this:

```
['nasa', 'nasa', 'esa', 'esa', 'jaxa', 'jaxa']
```

I can easily find which entries should be replaced with:

```
df_test.loc[df_test.source == 'unknown']
```

But I'm not sure how to replace them from this, any help is appreciated!

Comment: Is possible multiple difference values per same file if omit `unknown` in `source` column?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can convert `unknown` values to missing values in [`Series.mask`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.mask.html) and then use [`GroupBy.transform`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.transform.html) with first non missing value to new column:

*Notice: Solution working if `unknown`* value is first in some group.

```
df_test['new'] = (df_test['source'].mask(df_test.source == 'unknown')
                                   .groupby(df_test['file'])
                                   .transform('first'))
print (df_test)
     file   source   new
0  file_1     nasa  nasa
1  file_1  unknown  nasa
2  file_2      esa   esa
3  file_2  unknown   esa
4  file_3     jaxa  jaxa
5  file_3  unknown  jaxa
```

Or if only one non `unknown` value per `file`s create helper `Series` by [`boolean indexing`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#boolean-indexing) and [`DataFrame.set_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.set_index.html) and then [`Series.map`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.map.html):

```
s = df_test[df_test.source != 'unknown'].set_index('file')['source']

df_test['new'] = df_test['file'].map(s)
print (df_test)
     file   source   new
0  file_1     nasa  nasa
1  file_1  unknown  nasa
2  file_2      esa   esa
3  file_2  unknown   esa
4  file_3     jaxa  jaxa
5  file_3  unknown  jaxa
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do this by grouping by `file`, and setting all to the first instance of `source`:

```
df_test['source'] = df_test.groupby('file')['source'].transform('first')
```

Output:

```
    file    source
0   file_1  nasa
1   file_1  nasa
2   file_2  esa
3   file_2  esa
4   file_3  jaxa
5   file_3  jaxa
```

//Note, this assumes you always have a valid source listed first, not `unknown`, if that's not the case, the other answer is better as it removes them initially.